# How to change entrypoint on Nuxt build?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, nuxt.js

I have created an Nuxt app via CLI and I have chose SSR app with Node.js as a backend server. On my server Passenger is configured to run express apps from `app.js` file and I have no access to change it. Nuxts entry point is `server.js` by default. I was trying to find something on nuxt documentation but I cannot find anything useful.

I was searching in this website: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build

Also what I figured that those Js files are in ES6 module formating system but I also need CommonJS for run this app with Passenger. Is there any way to change this with .babelrc or webpack configuration??

Comment: it seems hardcoded : https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/79440f3ce5b90b39fc1fa68fe1736cac6edae491/packages/webpack/src/config/server.js#L117

Comment: Yeah but this is on webpack, how do you think can I change it ?

Comment: I think the best way it to create a symlink in your output build older from "app.js" to "server.js"

Comment: Can you paste this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Nicolas Pennec for pointing me to an answer.

When we want to run nuxt.js builded app via Passenger we actually don't need to rewrite webpack etc.

We need to build our nuxt app with:

```
yarn build
```

Result of that operation is newly created .next folder and only what's left to do that we need to start this folder with npm run start but with Passenger we cannot do this via command.

In our root folder on hosting like e.g. `public_nodejs` create app.js file (Passenger on my server requires main file to be called app.js)

The structure of files now looks like:

```
.next
app.js
package.json
```

Inside app.js simply write:

```
require("@nuxt/cli").run(["start"])
```

Install all dependencies and your nuxt js app will be running via Passenger

Answer (score 1):

The output name for Webpack is hardcoded in the [Nuxt source code](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/79440f3ce5b90b39fc1fa68fe1736cac6edae491/packages/webpack/src/config/server.js#L117).
So you cannot update it by configuration.

Currently the best way is to create a symlink in your output folder from "app.js" to "server.js" (maybe on "postbuild" script ?)