# How to specify written on TypeScript server side entry point in "Nuxt TypeScript" project?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

In the example of JavaScritpt-based Nuxt-project that I have seen, the server entry is in `server/index.js`, Here is it's default code (for Express.js framework case):

```js
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const {
    host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000
  } = nuxt.options.server

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

To start the server script with standard Nuxt building, the task called `dev` script has been changed changed to:

```
"cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
```

Now: what we have to do if we want to write the `server/index` in TypeScript (in [Nuxt TypeScript](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/) project)? Definitely, just rename `server/index.js` to `server/index.ts` will not be enough, because Nuxt must know what we are writing the source code in `server/index.ts` and must to compile it.

The Nuxt takes away the `Webpack` config from us with words "I'll take care about Webpack config, you should define the settings in nuxt.config.js". Well, but how we make Nuxt compile the `server.ts` now?

### Even more specifically

Assume that we have `index.ts` in the `server` subdirectory with `console.log("ok!)` content. How we should:

1. compile it to JavaScript,
2. start the server and get `ok!` feedback output in the terminal?

It's simple with Webpack but this case is TypeScript Nuxt project where direct configuration of Webpack is unavailable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268891/how-to-change-entrypoint-on-nuxt-build

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt.js has [official TypeScript support](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup) that can be found here:

Assuming you already have a `tsconfig.json` for your project, this is what you have left:

1. Add `@nuxt/typescript-build` as a devDependency
2. Add this line to your `nuxt.config.js`

```
buildModules: ['@nuxt/typescript-build']
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. All of above I have already done, but how it will activate `server/index.ts` compiling and how I should to execute the built result server entry point?

Comment: Assume we have `console.log("ok!")` in `server/index.ts`. How we can compile it, start the server and confirm `ok!` in console output?